# mysql does not have a weekyear function

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's take a look at what is weekyear:

*In the standard ISO8601 week algorithm, the first week of the year is that in which at least 4 days are in the year. As a result of this definition, day 1 of the first week may be in the previous year and the last day of a year may be in the first week of the next year*

consider date '2013-12-30' & '2013-12-31',in MySQL:

```
select weekofyear('2013-12-30')
```

return 1,means 2013-12-30 is in the first week of year 2014,so the weekyear of '2013-12-30' should be 2014,but in MySQL,I only found 2 year functions:

```
select year('2013-12-30') -- return 2013,certainly the year field
select yearweek('2013-12-30') -- return 201352,not correct,should be 201401
```

because that week left 3 days in 2013,and 4 days in 2014,so the weekyear of that day shoud be 2014.

How can i got the right result in mysql?

**UPDATE:**
I found that :

```
select yearweek('2013-12-30',3)
```

return 201401,that is the right result according to ISO8601 week algorithm,but how can I get weekyear 2014 and weekofyear 01 separately？

Comment: Would splitting the results not work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out,since yearweek(date,3) return a int with 6 digits,so i can get the year part by divide it by 100:

```
SELECT count(1) as count, yearweek(time,3) DIV 100 as year,weekofyear(time) as week FROM XXX
```

will give me what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:
You can use the mode parameter along with string functions to get the desired result, as follows:

```
select 
    LEFT(yearweek('2013-12-30', 3), 4) AS yr, 
    RIGHT(yearweek('2013-12-30', 3), 2) AS wk
```

**Reference**:

[YEARWEEK(date,mode) on MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek)

Comment: Thanks for answer,I use mode 3 in my project for the week algorithm

Comment: Please see revised answer above, which uses mode 3 and string functions to get year and week separately.

Comment: Thanks,@Joseph B,see my answer,the yearweek return an int with 6 digits,so i use DIV,not string function